# Haskell: manipulate data type of a defined class

Tags: haskell

I tried to comment everything to make my code very clear to everyone.  Please read the comment to better understand.

What I have so far, is a `Team` made up of players, and those players will eventually get a position: defender, middlefield, or striker.  For example, in:

```
let ykTeam = Team(Map.fromList [(1, [ 2, 3]),  (2, [1]), (3, [1, 4]), (4, [3])])
```

the item `(1, [ 2, 3])` means that player 1 can also play 2 or 3 (not so important right now).

**Question** : From the code shown below, I want to write the `initPlan` function, but I'm struggling to manipulate the `Plan` attribute `planMap :: Map.Map p Position`.

**Expected result:** When I try:

```
> initPlan $ team 4
```

I need to get:

```
Plan(def={}, mid={}, stk={1,2,3,4})
```

**Remark:** I'm used to `Map.Map v k` but not to `Map.Map v Position` ???

Any indications, ideas or hints are welcomed.

My code is:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- | The possible position of players on the field:
--
-- * `def`: the player is a defender in the team;
-- * `mid`: the player is a midlefield in the team;
-- * `stk`: the player is a stiker in the team;
data Position = Def | Mid | Stk
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Team t = Team (Map.Map t [t])

-- | A Plan for enumerating team position.
data Plan p = Plan {
    planMap   :: Map.Map p Position,
    planTeam  :: Team p
}

instance (Show p, Ord p) => Show (Plan p) where
    show p@(Plan playerToPosition _) = "Plan("
        ++ "defender={" ++ (showByPosition Def) ++ "}, "
        ++ "midlefield={" ++ (showByPosition Mid) ++ "}, "
        ++ "stiker={" ++ (showByPosition Stk) ++ "})"
        where showByPosition a = intercalate "," $ 
                map show $ playersByPosition a p

playersByPosition :: Ord p => Position -> Plan p -> [p]
playersByPosition position = Map.keys . Map.filter (== position) . planMap
```

My signature for `initPlan` is:

```
-- | It returns the plan of a given team
--
-- At the begenning, all players have position Stk.
--
-- >>> initPlan $ team 4
-- Plan(def={}, mid={}, stk={1,2,3,4})
initPlan :: Ord p => Team p -> Plan p
initPlan = ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably want:

```
initPlan :: Ord p => Team p -> Plan p
initPlan team@(Team tmap) = Plan pmap team
  where pmap = Map.fromList $ map (\plyr -> (plyr, Stk)) plyrs
        plyrs = Map.keys tmap
```

Given a `Team`, this gets the complete list of players (`plyrs`) from the keys in the underlying map.  Then we can construct, as a list, the pairs: `(1,Stk)`, `(2,Stk)` and so on that assign each player to the striker position, and then build the Map from that list.

You didn't provide a definition of the `team` function, so I don't know what `team 4` is supposed to look like, but using the `ykTeam` definition above seems to work:

```
> initPlan ykTeam
Plan(defender={}, midlefield={}, stiker={1,2,3,4})
>
```

Comment: team definition is like this team:: Int -> Team Int(4), It take a int and return a Team like so : Team(Map.fromList [(1, [ ]),  (2, []), (3, []), (4, [])]). My code is very long sorry.

Comment: I'll try this one

Comment: `pmap = Stk <$ tmap` (at which point you can maybe skip having a `where` block at all)?